# Wikitude - AR.TargetCollectionResource is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, android, wikitude

**I am trying to use the [wikitude-sdk-sample-image-recogn](https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-sdk-samples/tree/master/01_ImageRecognition_1_ImageOnTarget)  image recognition sample code which uses the wikitude Javscript SDK, to test how the image recognition feature works, when i run the code on my  android phone i get this error** [image]

This is the code which errors out,

```js
try{
        var targetCollectionResource = new AR.TargetCollectionResource(
   "/01_ImageRecognition_1_ImageOnTarget/assets/magazine.wtc", {
   onLoaded:function(){
    AR.logger.info("LOADED");
   },
   onError:function(err){
    AR.logger.info(`Error on target collection: ${err.message}`);
   }
        });
}catch (er) {
   AR.logger.error(er.message);
   
}
```

for some reason the its not recognising the TargetCollectionResource from the [Wikitude SDK API Reference](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/Reference/JavaScript%20API/classes/TargetCollectionResource.html)

Comment: It seems like you are specifying an absolute path for your .wtc which is probably incorrect, try to use a relative path from your html file instead. 
There is currently a known issue in the sdk where the onError message is not a valid string which causes an error in js which could explain why your catch block is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you would have resolved this issue... but even though sharing the solution with you.

Solution - issue was due to requiredFeatures is not set for the WTArchitectView as WTFeature_ImageTracking. I hope this will solve your issue.

eg - [WTArchitectView isDeviceSupportedForRequiredFeatures:WTFeature_ImageTracking|WTFeature_Geo error:&deviceSupportError];